# How to access all file without unzip any zip file in android?

Tags: android, zip, epub3

I am working on reading epub3 file and i want to access all files which used for create epub3 **without **unzip it***.*

any suggestion or solution would be appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to solve this and i got the following solution.

Zip is a one type of file Which include many directory and files so we can't get it in directory and file format. 
We can only get it in Bytes. Which is unused.
So we Have To Unzip it.....

Because Whenever we unzip it, then itself make one type of directory of sub directory and files So then we can access it in directory and file format.

Answer (score 2):

While you can technically read the bytes from the zip archive without decompressing them, it will not help you as the data will be unusable in any epub display.

When a file is zipped, it is compressed using compression tables. This alters the data of the file, and to get back the original data you must decompress, or unzip, it first.

Answer (score 2):

This is virtually no way to access files without unzipping. However, there is a way for targeted unzipping, i.e. unzipping a specific file instead of entire zipped folder. If that sounds good, you could probably go for [Objective zip](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip) project.

P.S: Even i was working on a epub3 reader and I had to unzip the entire folder. Let me know if you find a better work around.